# JSON: Controller parameter value has slash appended in its value

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on a simple project and want to send the JSON data to Controller

Here is my code:

```
var emailId = JSON.stringify(response.emails.account); // get email ID
$.ajax({
      url: "/Home/GetDetails",
      method: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { 'emailId': emailId },
      success: function (data) {
             // some logic here
      }
```

And my **Home** controller is:

```
public JsonResult GetDetails(string emailId){

   // logic here
}
```

The problem is JSON value of parameter **emailId** in controller is correct  but it is in the form **""abc@gmail.com""** instead of simple **"abc@gmail.com"** I get the "\ .. " as an extra appended in the parameter value which I would like to avoid. How can I avoid it? Also Why is it happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm confused. You not passing `liveId` anywhere

Comment: @JamesS, typo.. It is emailId not liveId. I edited my question

Comment: In the javascript as well?

Comment: @JamesS, no  only in Controller's parameter value.

Comment: So what is `emailId` in this case? Where is it set?

Comment: @JamesS, emailId is the Id that you get from windows live authentication. There is a page with a button,when you click it you will get emailId using response.emails.account which I am currently storing in emailId as you can see the first line of JS, this is then passed to controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, instead doing this:

```
var emailId = JSON.stringify(response.emails.account); // get email ID
```

You should JSON everything in the `data` section of your `ajax` call.

Such as

```
data: JSON.stringify({"emailId": response.emails.account}),
```